# Как создать универсальную функцию запросов к базе sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть функция -

```
def base_read(value, param, db_name):
    db = sqlite3.connect('serv.db')
    sql = db.cursor()

    # print(value) ssqws3
    # print(param) key
    # print(db_name) active_keys

  if sql.execute(f"SELECT key FROM active_keys WHERE key = '{value}'").fetchone() is None:
      db.close()
      return False

  else:
      db.close()
      return True
```

Выполняет простое действие. проверят есть ли элемент в базе.

sql я пока что так себе знаю. Но я пытаюсь написать универсальную функцию, дабы код не дублировался.
но в попытках указать -
Код не влез.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция отрабатывает некорректно. и возвращает не то, что ожидается.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, может я где в синтаксисе ошибку допускаю?

Подскажите, почему так происходит ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кавычки у колонок должны быть в другую сторону. Либо вообще не должно быть. Сейчас у вас получаются литералы вместо названий колонок. Возможно, я зря задубликатил, но на основную часть вопросов там есть ответы.

Comment: Спасибо большое,  
CrazyElf